# Mathematical modulus in c#

Tags: c#, modulo

Is there a library function in c# for the mathematical modulus of a number - by this I specifically mean that a negative integer modulo a positive integer should yield a positive result.

edited to provide an example:

-5 modulo 3 should return 1

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529440/533837 for a method that has less overflow problems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<strike>Try `(a % b) * Math.Sign(a)`</strike>

Try this; it works correctly.

```
static int MathMod(int a, int b) {
    return (Math.Abs(a * b) + a) % b;
}
```

Comment: This gives -5%4 = 1, but it should be 3.

Comment: +1 for being the first to post a correct algorithm (but watch out for overflow!). To strictly answer his question, though, no, there's nothing built into the framework for this.

Comment: much better than the no-brains-required while (a < 0) {a += b;}

Comment: Accepted as the first correct algorithm, but I think I am more likely to use ((a % b) + b) % b

Comment: the Math.Abs is very slow in this implementation, ((a % b) + b) % b is the fastest in my benchmarks using c# .net 4.

Comment: warning of overflow with this method !!

Comment: The only thing I would change is the names of the variables to dividend and divisor respectively, similarly to http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Modulo

Answer (score 8):

```
x < 0 ? ((x % m) + m) % m : x % m;
```

Comment: Why use the ternary operator?

Comment: @penguat: Because if x is non-negative then there is no reason to go through the extra work.

Comment: I'm not sure which is more work on average, the conditional or the fixed addition and modulus, not that it matters in my case. This answer is correct, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @penguat: Hard to say; I always consider division and modulus operations to be relatively expensive (unless they are trivial, as in divide by 2 or mod 2).  I imagine the overhead of the ternary operator is only a few cycles for the check and jumps.  Plus, there is no chance for overflow with non-negative x in this computation.  However, without the ternary operator, you could overflow if `x = 1` and `m = int.MaxValue` (or in any scenario where 0 < x < m and x + m > int.MaxValue).

Comment: I would definitely guess that the extra modulo is faster than the branch on modern processors.  However, I've never tested it, so I don't really know.  Also, it's a pretty slight distinction.

I'm not sure which is more readable.  I was going to say without the ternary operator at first, but when I think about it that x < 0 does tell the reader why we're doing something fancy without having the need for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Well the definition (if I'm not mistaken) is something like this

a mod b = a - b * floor(a/b)

It's probably pretty slow and beware of integer division just like built in modulus :)

Other option is to modify the result of built-in modulus according to the signs of operands. Something like this:

```
if(a < 0 && b > 0)
{
    return (a % b + b) % b;
}
else if ....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a < 0 ? ((a+1)%b + b-1) : (a%b);
```

That requires only one % operation (`and one ternary op`) and no multiplication

Answer (score 1):

If you're using any of these algorithms and you need to do division also, don't forget to make sure that you subtract 1 when appropriate.

I.e.,

if `-5 % 2 = -1` and `-5 / 2 = -2`, and if you care that `-5 / 2 * 2 + -5 % 2 = -5`, then when you calculate `-5 % 2 = 1`, that you also calculate `-5 / 2 = -3`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here... I'd normally preserve the original number rather than try to reconstruct it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you reconstruct it.  I was just concerned that your algorithm might use the / operator as well and depend on them being consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Fix :

(ans=a%b)<0 ? (a<0 && b<0 ? (ans-b)%(-b) : (ans+b)%b) : ans

Comment: what about -10 mod 3? your solution would give -1 where the required answer is 2.

Comment: @penguat
  a=-10 , b=3 
  ans= -1 < 0  , so  solution = (-1+3) % 3 =2  
  what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question didn't ask for it, but I just wrote and tested a method which returns the quotient as well. Didn't find this when I was looking for it, so I thought I'd put it out there.

```
/// <summary>
/// Compute integer quotient and remainder of <paramref name="dividend"/> / <paramref name="divisor"/>
/// where the <paramref name="remainder"/> has the same sign as <paramref name="divisor"/>, and is
/// between zero (inclusive) and the <paramref name="divisor"/> (exclusive). As always,
/// (quotientResult * <paramref name="divisor"/> + <paramref name="remainder"/> == <paramref name="dividend"/>).
/// </summary>
public static int DivRemPeriodic(int dividend, int divisor, out int remainder) {
    var quotient = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, out remainder);
    if (divisor > 0 ? remainder < 0 : remainder > 0) {
        remainder += divisor;
        quotient -= 1;
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: The remainder here is equivalent to the modulus I was asking for - with the quotient as well. This may have a different result for divisors less than zero.

Comment: Doh! Yep, I meant "returns the quotient as well." Corrected. It works for negative divisors with result as given in the comment doc. Remainder (aka "modulus") will have same sign as divisor. For a negative divisor, the modulus is periodic over the range (-divisor,0].

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operation is the reminder of a division and this exists in Math:

```
double module = Math.IEEERemainder(x, y);
```

Comment: Modulus is not the same as remainder, it's just unfortunate naming in programming. Modulus and remainder do partially overlap - i.e. produce the same result for many numbers, but not all. (Also the method you posted is specifically for floating-point numbers, which is slightly different.)

Answer (score -3):

Might be the % operator?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: No this doesn't yield a positive result when doing -5 % 2

Comment: He wants `-5 % 2` to be **+1**, not -1.