# Hex remove leading digits

Tags: c

When you do something like `0x01AE1 - 0x01AEA = fffffff7`. I only want the last 3 digits. So I used the modulus trick to remove the extra digits. The displacement gets filled with hex values.

```
  int extra_crap = 0; 
  int extra_crap1 = 0; 
  int displacement = 0;
  int val1 = 0;
  int val2 = 0;

  displacement val1 - val2;
  extra_crap = displacement % 0x100;
  extra_crap1 = displacement % 256;
  printf(" extra_crap is %x \n", extra_crap);
  printf(" extra_crap1 is %x \n", extra_crap1);
```

Unfortunately this is having no effect at all. Is there another way to remove all but the last 3 digits?

Comment: What are your data types? How do you output the data?

Comment: A couple suggested edits: `0x01AE1 - 0x01AEA = fffffff7` and in your program: `int displacement =  0x01AE1 - 0x01AEA;` so people have a hope of seeing the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @ Michael Burr thank you for catching that my numbers were backwards. CiaPan figured out a working solution. I don't wanna put those numbers in my code because after every iteration the numbers change. I use this block of code many times in one of my functions.

Comment: @Kevin are saying to cast it or use unsigned ints from the beginning?

Comment: `displacement` should be unsigned, doesn't really matter if `val1` and `val2` are.

Answer (score 3):

*'Unfortunately this is having no effect at all.'*

That's probably because you do your calculations on *signed* int. Try casting the value to `unsigned`, or simply forget the remainder operator `%` and use bitwise masking:

```
displacement & 0xFF;
displacement & 255;
```

for two hex digits or

```
displacement & 0xFFF;
displacement & 4095;
```

for three digits.

**EDIT – some explanation**

A detailed answer would be quite long... You need to learn about data types used in C (esp. `int` and `unsigned int`, which are two of most used [Integral types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_type)), the range of values that can be represented in those types and their internal representation in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) code. Also about [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and [Hexadecimal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Then you will easily get what happened to your data: subtracting `0x01AE1 - 0x01AEA`, that is `6881 - 6890`, gave the result of `-9`, which in 32-bit signed integer encoded with 2's complement and printed in hexadecimal is `FFFFFFF7`. That MINUS NINE divided by 256 gave a quotient ZERO and [Remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) MINUS NINE, so the remainder operator `%` gave you a precise and correct result. What you call *'no effect at all'* is just a result of your lack of understanding what you were actually doing.

My answer above (variant 1) is not any kind of magic, but just a way to enforce calculation on positive numbers. Casting values to `unsigned` type makes the program to interpret `0xFFFFFFF7` as 4294967287, which divided by 265 (0x100 in hex) results in quotient 16777215 (0xFFFFFF) and remainder 247 (0xF7). Variant 2 does no division at all and just 'masks' those necessary bits: numbers 255 and 4095 contain 8 and 12 low-order bits equal 1 (in hexadecimal 0xFF and 0xFFF, respectively), so [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_and#AND) does exactly what you want: removes the higher part of the value, leaving just the required two or three low-order hex dgits.

Comment: "Probably": see [c - Modulo operation with negative answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers)

Comment: @CiaPan That worked perfectly :). Can you please explain why it worked?

Comment: The comment is too short for the explanation, so I append it to the answer.