# Why is modulo not functioning correctly in this C code?

Tags: c, modulo

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%d\r\n", -1 % 7);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it prints `-1`. According to my own math and calculators like this one (http://www.miniwebtool.com/modulo-calculator/?number1=-1&number2=7), my answer should be 6. Im assuming there is some 'gotcha' in the C implementation of modulo that I am not grasping. Can someone explain why I am not getting the answer I expect?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers

Comment: FWW: `-1 % 7` also returns `-1` in JavaScript, but it does return `6` in Python.

Comment: So what do I need to do to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The rule of C (after C99) is that the sign of the result of `i%j` is same as the sign of `i`. The answer you are getting is correct.

In C89 the result of `i%j` (if either `i` or `j` is negative) depends on the implementation. `-1%7` could either be `-1` or `6`.