# What's wrong in this c code?

Tags: c, algorithm, integer, integer-division

This is a question on Codeforces, [link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/597/A)

Find the number of **k-divisible** numbers on the segment `[a , b]`. In other words you need to find the number of such integer values `x` that `a ≤ x ≤ b` and `x` is divisible by `k`.

**Input:**
The only line contains three space-separated integers `k`, `a` and `b`
(1 ≤ k ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>;   -10<sup>18</sup> ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>).

**Output:**
Print the required number.

And below is my source code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

int count(int k,int a, int b)
{
   if(a>b)
      return 0;

   if(a%k!=0)
      return count(k,a+1,b);

   return 1+count(k,a+1,b);
}

int main()
{
    int k,a,b,counter;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&k,&a,&b);

    if(k==0)
       counter=0;
    else
       counter=count(k,a,b);

    printf("%d",counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I submit my code ,I get this reply `wrong answer at test 57`. So, if someone could help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Very poorly indented code and looks more like a math question than C.

Comment: `- 1018 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 1018` pay attention to negative numbers! Modulus operations can be surprising with them.

Comment: ^ excellent point. e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11720841/2757035

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a for loop:

```
for (int i = a; i < b; ++i) {
    if ((i % k) == 0) {
        printf("%d can be divided by %d\n", i, k);
        ++counter;
    }
}
printf("There are %d numbers divisible by %d between %d and %d\n", counter, k, a, b);
```

Will output:

```
-28 can be divided by 7
-21 can be divided by 7
-14 can be divided by 7
-7 can be divided by 7
0 can be divided by 7
7 can be divided by 7
14 can be divided by 7
21 can be divided by 7
28 can be divided by 7
There are 9 numbers divisible by 7 between -30 and 30
```

If you enter inputs: `7`, `-30`, `30`

Answer (score 0):

This is a math problem, really. We have

> 1 ≤ *k* ≤ 10<sup>18</sup> < 2<sup>60</sup>
>   -10<sup>18</sup> ≤ *a* ≤ *b* ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>

so we need `inttypes.h` and `int64_t` to be able to describe *a* and *b*; it'll also work for *k*. To scan the three values, the pattern `"%" SCNd64 " %" SCNd64 " %d" SCNd64 ""` will work. To print, use pattern `"%" PRId64 ""`. (The `inttypes.h` header file that contains these was standardized in ISO C99, and is also defined in POSIX.)

The actual problem at hand is to find the number of unique integers `n` for which

> *a* ≤ *n* *k* ≤ *b*

where *a* and *b* are integers, and *k* is a positive integer. The smallest and largest *n* fulfill

> *a* ≤ *n<sub>min</sub>* *k*
>   *b* ≥ *n<sub>max</sub>* *k*

that can be written also as

> *a* ÷ *k* ≤ *n<sub>min</sub>* 
>   *b* ÷ *k* ≥ *n<sub>max</sub>*

where `÷` denotes ordinary division. The number we need to print is the number of unique *n*, or

> *n<sub>max</sub>* - *n<sub>min</sub>* + 1

If we use `/` for integer division (as done in C, i.e. truncating division), `ceil()` for *ceil* (rounding towards positive infinity), and `floor()` for *floor* (rounding towards negative infinity), and we remember *k* is a positive integer, we can write the inequalities as

> *a* ÷ *k* ≤ ceil( *a* ÷ *k* ) =  *n<sub>min</sub>* 
>   *b* ÷ *k* ≥ floor( *b* ÷ *k* ) = *n<sub>max</sub>*

and the number to be printed is

> floor( *b* ÷ *k* ) - ceil( *a* ÷ *k* ) + 1

Although the standard C library provides functions `ceil()` and `floor()` in `math.h`, they only work for floating-point numbers (but even double-precision floating point does not have integer precision over the range -10<sup>18</sup> to +10<sup>18</sup>). Instead, we need to use integer rounding "tricks":

> ceil( *x* ÷ *k* ) = (*x* + *k* - 1) / *k*,   *x* > 0, *k* > 0 
>   ceil( *x* ÷ *k* ) = *x* / *k*,   *x* ≤ 0, *k* > 0 
>     
>   floor( *x* ÷ *k* ) = *x* / *k*,   *x* ≥ 0, *k* > 0 
>   floor( *x* ÷ *k* ) = (*x* - *k* + 1) / *k*,   *x* < 0, *k* > 0

The only limitation here is that our integer type must be able to represent numbers from *a*-*k* to *b*+*k*, inclusive. Since `int64_t` can represent range (roughly) -9.22×10<sup>18</sup> to +9.22×10<sup>18</sup>, we're well covered.

For the actual solution program, you need to scan *a*, *b*, *k* (and I already mentioned the correct patterns for `int64_t`), verify *a* ≤ *b* and *k* ≥ 1, calculate *n<sub>max</sub>* and *n<sub>min</sub>* using the above math, and finally print the result (again, I mentioned the printf pattern to use for `int64_t`). It's very straightforward, if you have the math firmly in your grasp.