# How to divide an integer number with another number greater than zero and give remainer

Tags: c++

My programs does its function when both numbers are positive but when one of them is negative it does not.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b;
    b > 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int d;
    d = a/b;
    int r;
    r = a%b;
    cout << d << " " << r << endl;
}
```

In my program:

- 32/6 = 5 2 (division and remainder)
- -32/6 = -5 -2 (division and remainder)

What program is supposed to do:

- 32/6 = 5 2 (division and remainder)
- -32/6 = -6 4 (division and remainder)

Comment: Please copy the code here..

Comment: Look up "modulo" or "modulus" in your favorite C++ or mathematical references.  You could also search Wikipedia!

Comment: [FYI] C++ modulo does not work like it does in pure mathematics.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder

Comment: If you'd posted your code as text instead of as a picture you wouldn't be getting so many recommendations to use `%`. Nobody wants to look at pictures of code.

Comment: [Modulo operation with negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11720656/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work myself. For anyone who needs a program like this here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int d = a/b;
    int r = a%b;
    if (r < 0){
        d = d-1;
        int s = d*b;
        r = -s+a;
    }
    cout << d << " " << r << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `modulus` operator, `'%'`.

```
int a = 5 % 2;
cout << a << endl;
```

The modulus operator returns the remainder of the first value divided by the second.