# Average of even numbers gives back wrong value

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to get closer to understanding streams thus I'm doing some basic exercises. In this one, I'd like to calculate the average of the odd numbers. I wrote this algorithm to do so, but it gives back an incorrect result (8.0). I've tried to debug it but I couldn't find what it does actually.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 3, -2, -4, -7, -3, -8, 12, 19, 6, 9, 10, 14);

OptionalDouble result = numbers.stream()
                               .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1)
                               .mapToDouble(i -> i).average();
if (result.isPresent()) {
   System.out.println(result);
} else {
   System.out.println("Error");
}
```

What is my code doing now? How should I fix it to do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Your filter is only retaining positive odd numbers.

Comment: your title says you want an average of even numbers and your description says the opposite. what do you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(i -> i % 2 == 1)
```

This is only true for positive odd numbers, because in Java the `%` operator returns a negative number (or zero) if its first operand is negative.

If you want to retain only *even* numbers, it should be:

```
(i -> i % 2 == 0)
```

If you want to retain all odd numbers (positive and negative), you can use:

```
(i -> i % 2 != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is my code doing now?

You're performing a [modulo operation on negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers).

> How should I fix it to do what it's supposed to do?

You can use `Math.abs` to validate the absolute value is odd or not in your list:

```
OptionalDouble result = numbers.stream()
                .filter(i -> Math.abs(i) % 2 == 1) // verify id the absolute value is odd
                .mapToDouble(i->i).average();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008089/average-of-even-numbers-gives-back-wrong-value/54008133#54008133) mentioned regarding modulo with negative numbers.

It's important to know that, the `filter` intermediate operation **does not remove elements** nor does any stream operation, instead, `filter` returns a new stream in which all the elements satisfying the provided predicate i.e. `i -> i % 2 == 1` are present.

`i -> i % 2 == 1` is saying "only keep the element represented as `i` if it's an **odd number**".

if you want even then you should do `i -> i % 2 == 0`, reads as "only keep the element represented as `i` is it's an **even number**".

---

On another note, if you're running on JDK9 you can use `ifPresentOrElse` to simply the `isPresent()` check.

```
 numbers.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .mapToDouble(i -> i)
        .average()
        .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,
                        () -> System.out.println("Error"));
```