# Why 5 % -2 is giving 1 in C language

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 5 % -2;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Normally, it should return me -1 as an output. However, it is returning 1 instead.Why??

Comment: *Normally, it should return me* - what does it mean "normally"? This operator is well defined *"When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a;"* Here `a/b` is `-2`, therefore `(a/b)*b + a%b = -2*-2 +1 == 5 = a` - as required

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers

Comment: The `%` is not a direct implementation of the mathematical *mod*.