# How to reset counter in loop

Tags: c#, loops

Here is my code

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            i++;
            i = i % 10;
        }
```

The above code resets the counter to 0 when it reaches the limit.
Just wanted to Is there a way to do some thing similar in the below code replacing the if condition

```
        int i = 10;
        while (i > -1)
        {
            i--;
            if (i == -1)
                i = 10;
        }
```

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What is this for, anyway?

Comment: are you sure the first part resets the counter

Comment: I assume this is just a simplified version, since you would just want an infinite loop if that's what you really wanted. Can you show us something a little closer to your real situation so we can give you a better answer that will work for your real loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691025/mathematical-modulus-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you provide any more insight as to what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Both your loops are `while(true)` so they play no role in the question.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver just wanted to know if dere is a similar way to reset the counter using some thing like mod or any other function

Comment: if `%` was actually a mathematical "modulus" then the first code would handle the second case, but it's not (negative numbers are handled differently).  You could make a method that implemented the actual "modulus" functionality in which case it would handle both cases.  [read for more info](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fericlippert%2Farchive%2F2011%2F12%2F05%2Fwhat-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx&ei=1sJhUO7THqWG0QGT6IGYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFm6xs9VJSMWnTEQwl44GyU6XAycg&cad=rja)

Comment: @jade did you got solved?,you can try my answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your loops are `while(true)` so they play no role in the question.

That leaves: "can I make a count-down roll over without an if?"

The answer is yes, if you realy want to:

```
 i--;
 i = (i + 10) % 10;
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but this solution does not reset to 10 but to 9. Suppose we output the values at the entry point of the loop: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 and not 10. It is correct though, if we take the output at the end of the loop :)

Comment: Also, why do you do `i--` and then `i+10`? That's so inefficient! Why not a single `i+9`?

Comment: "so inefficient" - did you check the C# and Jitter optimizations? At this level only readability counts.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i = 10;
    while (true)
    {
        i = (i + 10) % 11;
    }
```

This would give you:

```
10 -> 9
9 -> 8
8 -> 7
7 -> 6
6 -> 5
4 -> 3
3 -> 2
2 -> 1
1 -> 0
0 -> 10
```

Comment: Yes, this loop seems to have length of 11, depending on how/where `i` is used.

Answer (score 0):

By using this you can reset the value of i to 0 when reaches the limit 10.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
{
   i++;
   if(i==10)
   {
      i=0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first loop iterates over the numbers 0..9. You can make your code iterate over 9..0 in the same way:

```
int i = 10;
while (i > -1)
{
    i--;
    i = i % 10;
}
```

Comment: `%` isn't actually the modulus, it's the remainder.  [They aren't the same thing.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fericlippert%2Farchive%2F2011%2F12%2F05%2Fwhat-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx&ei=1sJhUO7THqWG0QGT6IGYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFm6xs9VJSMWnTEQwl44GyU6XAycg&cad=rja)