# Increment Only To A Specific Number Then Start Increments Over

Tags: c#

I have the following code that is working to an extent. The problem, however, is the pick numbers should only go up to the number of teams (in this case there's only 6 teams so the picks should be listed at 1-6). Obviously just doing i++ will get me i from 1-30. Is there any way to only increment the number up to a specific point and start it all over?

```
internal List<Draft> DraftOrder
{
    get
    {
        List<Draft> _draftorder = new List<Draft>();
        List<DraftPick> teamPicks = new List<DraftPick>();
        foreach (Team t in teams.OrderBy(t => t.winpct))
        {
            teamPicks.AddRange(t.DraftPicks.Where(s => s.season == season));
        }

        int i = 1;
        foreach (DraftPick d in teamPicks)
        {
            _draftorder.Add(new Draft
            {
                team = teams.Find(t => t.teamid == d.currentTeamId).TeamName,
                round = d.round,
                pick = i++
            });
        }
        return _draftorder;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i = (i + 1) % max`

Comment: You really shouldnt have all that logic in your property getter...

Comment: At the end of the loop: `if(i == 6) { i = 1;}`

Comment: @zeal that is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset counter in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585244/how-to-reset-counter-in-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you...

```
internal List<Draft> DraftOrder
{
 get
 {
    List<Draft> _draftorder = new List<Draft>();
    List<DraftPick> teamPicks = new List<DraftPick>();
    foreach (Team t in teams.OrderBy(t => t.winpct))
    {
        teamPicks.AddRange(t.DraftPicks.Where(s => s.season == season));
    }

    int i = 1;
    foreach (DraftPick d in teamPicks)
    {
        _draftorder.Add(new Draft
        {
            team = teams.Find(t => t.teamid == d.currentTeamId).TeamName,
            round = d.round,
            pick = i++
        });

         if(i==6) //ADD CODE
            i=1;
    }
    return _draftorder;
 }
}
```