# How to set so if loop hits max number it starts over again

Tags: c#

Need quick help from who knows. I need to do so number never goes over max value

```
var MaxValue = 100;

var anynumber = 95 + 9; //( = 4, and not 104)
```

Comment: `var anynumber = (95 + 9) % MaxValue;`

Comment: Have you tried anything, in code, that you could share with us? May be, pointing the issue why you failed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset counter in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585244/how-to-reset-counter-in-loop)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [modulo (or "remainder") operator `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-):

```
var anynumber = (95 + 9) % MaxValue;
```